# connection between android app and cakephp

Tags: php, android, cakephp

Hi I'm making a web service in cakephp for an android app. I am getting the request and the respose is being send but the response is not visible on the client's end. My code is as shown below. Can there be some other method to send the response.

```
public function AndroidApp() {

    if (isset($_POST["myHttpData"])) {

       $coupon = trim($_POST["myHttpData"]);


        $couponId = $this->Code->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Code.coupon_code' => $coupon,
                'Code.status' => 'Used'
            ),
            'fields' => array('Code.id')));

        $studentAssessmentId = $this->StudentAssessment->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'StudentAssessment.code_id' => $couponId[0]['Code']['id'],
                'StudentAssessment.status' => 'Complete'
            ),
            'fields' => array('StudentAssessment.id')));

        $scores = $this->AssessmentScore->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'AssessmentScore.student_assessment_id' => $studentAssessmentId[0]['StudentAssessment']['id']
            ),
            'fields' => array('AssessmentScore.score')));

        $json = array();
        $assessment_data = array();

        //debug($scores);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($scores as $score) {
            $assessment_data[$i] = array("score" => $score['AssessmentScore']['score']);
            $i+=1;
        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');


        $json['success'] = $assessment_data;

        $android = json_encode($json);
    } else {
        $json['error'] = "Sorry, no score is available for this coupon code!";
        $android = json_encode($json);
    }
    echo $android;
```

Comment: Do you try debug it with a browser? Create a form that simulate the request.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You're not using CakePHPs request and response objects but plain php (Why are you using Cake at all then?), CakePHP can serialize the output on json request automatically (see book.cakephp.org) and most of this code should go into a model. Use a tool like Charles to debug the requests and responses.

Comment: Also, you seem to use a 'post' request to *retrieve* data, strictly you should use a 'get' request for this purpose. 'post' request are meant for adding/updating data (making changes), 'get' request to read/view data.

Answer (score 0):

### code smell, non-cakephp standards

First of all, as mentioned in comments by others, you're not using the CakePHP request/response objects. Because of this, you're overly complicating things. See the documentation here;
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types

And

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

The `$scores` loop to reformat the query results is probably redundant if you replace the `find('all')` with `find('list')`, using 'score' as display field. See the documentation here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

### bugs

There also seems to be some bugs in your code;

- the content-type header is only sent if `$_POST["myHttpData"]` is present.
- you're only checking if `$_POST["myHttpData"]` is *present*, not if it actually contains any data (empty)
- you're *not* checking if the various queries return a result. This will cause errors in your code if a query did not return anything! For example, you **assume** that `$couponId[0]['Code']['id']` is present (but it won't be if the coupon-code was not found)

### possible answer

Apart from these issues, the most probable cause for your problem is that you did not disable 'autoRender'. Therefore CakePHP will also render the view after you've output your JSON, causing a malformed JSON response.

```
public function AndroidApp() {
     $this->autoRender = false;

     // rest of your code here

}
```